# Как передать в метод дополнительный параметр?

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Имеется массив строк:

```
String[] str = {"один", "два", "три", "четыре", "пять", "шесть", "семь"};
```

Имеется метод, который принимает массив строк и выполняет с ним какие-либо действия:

```java
public static void methodStr(String[] s) {
    // code
}
```

**Вопрос:** как правильно передать определенные элементы массива String'ов? Например, нужно передать только `str[3]`, `str[4]` и `str[5]` элементы -  `public static void methodStr(str[с 3-го по 5-й])`?

**Важно:** без создания нового `String[]`!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001759/7791165, разве ArraySegment не относится к C#?

Comment: Извиняюсь, уже подправил

Comment: `methodStr(String[] s)` => `methodStr(String[] s, int startIndex, int endIndex)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String - ссылочный тип данных, как и массив. Это значит, что при передаче его в аргументы метода, вы передаете ссылку на объект. Ссылок может быть много, а объект один.

Например:
String s1 = "value";
String s2 = s1;

Теперь в результате вывода и переменной s1 и s2 в консоль вы увидите value. Вместе с тем, это лишь ссылки, в памяти будет хранится только одно значение - value.
Это же происходит при передаче массива. Мы передаем массив массив и работаем с ним как с ссылкой. Фактическое копирование не происходит.

В вашей ситуации есть несколько вариантов:

1) methodStr(String[] s, int startIndex, int endIndex) - то, что уже вам предложено. Передавать весь массив в метод, а работать только с элементами , которые расположены в пределах индексов int startIndex, int endIndex

2) произвести копирование нужной части массива и передать его в метод

3) изменить сигнатуру с methodStr(String[] s) на methodStr(String ... s) . После этого при вызове данного метода вы можете передать в его аргументы произвольное количество только нужных элементов массива через запятую. Например, имея массив String[] str = {"один", "два", "три", "четыре", "пять", "шесть", "семь"}; для того, чтобы передать в метод элементы с 0 до 2 включительно нужно вызвать данный метод таким образом: methodStr(str[0], str[1], str[2]);

В последнем случае вы можете передавать в аргументы метода любые элементы массива (любое их количество и в любом порядке, т.е. не обязательно именно так, как они расположены в исходном массиве).

Посему у вас всего несколько вариантов... Сделать так, как предложено выше, т.е. передать весь массив и работать только с элементами в пределах startIndex и endIndex. скопировать часть массива и передать его в параметры. инменить сигнатру public static void methodStr(String[] s)

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить ещё один метод с дополнительным параметром `int... filter` - какие строки обрабатывать. Чтобы старый функционал остался прежним, его надо будет немного доплилить:

```java
public static void methodStr(String[] s) {
    methodStr(s, IntStream.range(0, s.length).toArray());
}

public static void methodStr(String[] s, int... filter) {
    Arrays.stream(filter).mapToObj(i -> s[i]).forEach(str -> {
        // code
    });
}
```